# How to paint in green every column in ccf () plot, which has the value above 0.07 or below -0.07?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot cross-correlation plot (ccf()) in such way that every lag which is higher than +0.07 or lower than -0.07 should be paint in green. My example and the plot that I am generating now is shown in the following text. 
Every assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have 2 time series:

```
MU_Diff1_ten<-c(-0.1,0,0.08,0.15,0.08,-0.05,0.02,0.03,-0.04,-0.03,-0.03,0,0.02,-0.09,0.03,-0.02,-0.03,0.08,-0.01,0.01,-0.01,0,0,0,-0.04,0.02,0.03,-0.02,0.02,-0.01,-0.04,0.02,0.01,-0.07,-0.01,-0.05,0.02,0.05,-0.07,0.13,0,0.02,0.02,0.07,0,-0.07,0.02,0.01,-0.03,-0.03,-0.01,0.02,0,0,0,0,-0.03,0.01,0.02,-0.02,-0.01,-0.02,0.01,-0.02,0.06,-0.01,0,-0.04,0.03,-0.03,0.03,0.01,-0.03,0.03,-0.01,0.01,0,-0.12,-0.02,-0.01,-0.09,0.1,-0.06,0.04,0.03,-0.06,-0.06,0,0.04,-0.03,-0.05,0,-0.01,-0.01,0.02,-0.03,-0.03,-0.01,0.05,-0.02,-0.06,-0.1,-0.09,-0.09,-0.12,0.1,-0.08,-0.09,-0.02,0.03,0.24,0.09,0.08,0,0,0.03,0.07,-0.04,0.05,0,-0.03,-0.04,0.06,-0.04,-0.03,-0.06,0.08,-0.04,-0.04,-0.02,-0.05,-0.04,0,0.01,-0.09,0,-0.02,-0.06,-0.03,0.11,0,-0.03,-0.11,0.02,-0.04,0.04,-0.06,-0.01,0.12,-0.04,0.13,-0.13,0.08,-0.05,-0.01,-0.13,-0.28,0.02,0.04,0.11,-0.1,-0.16,0.05,0.03,-0.03,0.12,-0.07,-0.06,0.02,-0.03,0,-0.09,-0.03,-0.01,0.02,0.02,0.11,-0.01,0,-0.08,-0.09,0.09,0.03,-0.03,-0.02,0.04,0.03,-0.03,0.02,0.01,-0.02,0.02,-0.02,0.02,0.33,-0.11,0,-0.09,0.06,0.03,0.03,0,-0.05,0,0.02,-0.01,-0.02,-0.07,0.02,-0.01,-0.01,0.06,0.07,-0.06,0.01,-0.03,0.02,0.01,-0.05,0,-0.09,-0.06,-0.04,-0.01,0.08,-0.08,0.07,0.01,-0.04,-0.03,-0.01,-0.02,0.03,0.08,-0.18,0.06,-0.08,0,0.02,0.06,0.02,0.11,-0.13,0.02,-0.08,-0.01,0.04,-0.04,0.07,0,0,0.02,-0.01,-0.08,0,-0.06,0.02,-0.02,0.03,0,0,-0.06,0,0.04,-0.04,0.01,-0.02,0.02,0.07,0,0.04,0.07,0.11,-0.03,-0.09,-0.1,-0.04,0.03,0.07,-0.04,-0.01,-0.04,0.03,0.03,0.01,-0.02,0.05,0.02,0.02,0,0.01,-0.06,-0.03,0.01,-0.01,-0.06,0.02,-0.06,0.03,0.05,-0.02,0,-0.05,-0.01,0.02,-0.1,0.04,0.04,0.04,-0.02,0.15,-0.12,-0.01,0.06,0.06,-0.09,0.07,0.02,0.09,0.05,-0.02,0.06,0.05,-0.06,-0.03,-0.07,0.05,0,0.11,0.01,0,0.08,0.01,0.03,0.07,-0.03,0.15,-0.04,0.03,-0.04,-0.08,0.07,-0.01,-0.11,-0.01,-0.05,-0.11,-0.05,0.04,0.11,0.25,0.12,-0.02,0.03,0.06,0.05,0,-0.09,0,0.04,0.03,-0.04,0,0.04,0.05,0,0.08,-0.02,0.01,0.01,-0.02,0.01,-0.01,0,-0.01,-0.03,-0.02,0.03,0.02,0.02,-0.03,0.01,0.03,0.02,0.03,-0.01,-0.01,0,0,-0.17,-0.01,-0.04,-0.1,0.01,0.13,-0.05,0,0.03,0.07,-0.04,-0.07,0,-0.04,0.01,0.04,-0.04,0.02,0.01,0.04,-0.03,-0.04,-0.07,0.02,0.05,-0.01,0,-0.06,0,-0.09,0.06,0,0.01,-0.03,0.02,0.01,0.04,0.01,0.03,-0.03,-0.04,-0.39,0.03,-0.07,0.17,0.05,-0.02,0.05,-0.13,0.05,-0.08,0.1,-0.06,0.05,0.01,-0.03,0,0.06,0.04,0.11,0.01,-0.01,0,0,-0.03,-0.07,0.06,0.02,0.1,-0.04,0.02,0.04,-0.03,0.04,-0.03,-0.03,0.02,0,-0.25,-0.08,-0.03,0.17,0.09,0,0.01,-0.05,-0.17,0.04,-0.11,0.08,-0.09,0.1,0.05,-0.11,0,0.05,0.05,0.02,-0.05,0.01,-0.08,-0.01,-0.04,0.04,0.05,-0.07,-0.03,0.02,0,0,-0.03,0,0.04,-0.03,0.02,0.01,0.03,-0.04,0.05,0.13,-0.2,-0.1,0.05,-0.08,-0.07,0.07,0.15,-0.04,0.15,0,0.03,0,0.07,0.03,0.06,0.1,0.06,0.05,-0.06,0.04,0.06,-0.09,-0.02,-0.04,0.05,-0.01,-0.08,0,0.04,0.05,-0.08,0,0.06,0.01,0.03,-0.01,0.08,-0.15,0.04,0.04,0.05,-0.01,-0.04,0.01,0.05,0.08,0,0.04,-0.02,-0.06,0.02,0.05,0,0.01,0.01,-0.09,-0.06,-0.09,0.06,-0.07,-0.02,0.02,0.03,-0.09,-0.06,0.03,-0.04,0.04,-0.07,-0.04,0.03,0.02,0.02,-0.01,0.02,-0.19,-0.11,0.06,0.06,0.02,0.02,-0.01,0,0.12,0.06,0.1,0.1,-0.1,-0.02,-0.08,0.04,0.04,0,0,0.08,0.02,-0.04,0,-0.06,0.04,0.01,-0.04,-0.01,-0.03,0.05,0.03,-0.02,-0.03,0.03,-0.09,0.03,-0.02,0.04,0.07,-0.1,-0.03,0.01,0.07,-0.03,-0.08,-0.1,-0.06,0.08,0.02,0.06,-0.12,0.02,-0.01,-0.13,-0.08,-0.07,-0.02,-0.2,-0.01,-0.11,-0.19,0.19,0.13,-0.02,0.04,-0.13,-0.14,-0.02,0.03,0.14,-0.13,0.02,-0.12,-0.04,0.02,0.2,0.15,0.02,-0.13,-0.04,-0.18,0.37,-0.03,0.03,0.01,0.03,-0.09,0.01,-0.03,0.01,-0.07,0.05,0.01,-0.07,0.01,-0.02,0.07,0.01,-0.03,-0.04,0.02,-0.07,-0.01,-0.01,0.11,-0.02,0.05,0.02,0.02,-0.03,-0.11,-0.02,0.01,0.03,0.01,-0.06,0.03,0.15,-0.06,-0.09,0.04,-0.04,0.03,-0.01,-0.04,0.06,0.03,-0.01,-0.03,-0.04,0.04,0.01,-0.01,0.04,-0.03,-0.06,-0.03,0.08,-0.05,0.02,0.04,0.04,-0.03,0.03,-0.02,-0.02,0.06,-0.09,0.02,0.02,-0.02,-0.04,-0.04,0.03,-0.06,0.05,0.02,-0.05,-0.01,-0.05,0.03,-0.06,0,0.14,0.03,0.05,0.08,-0.05,0,-0.02,0.06,0.1,0.02,-0.03,0.07,-0.02,0.07,0.06,-0.01,0.09,0.04,0.08,-0.05,0.01,0.03,0.01,-0.02,-0.04,-0.01,0.01,-0.02,-0.03,0.02,0.02,0.01,0,0.02,0.03,-0.02,-0.05,-0.02,-0.06,-0.07,0.08,-0.01,0.01,-0.08,-0.06,0.04,-0.01,0.06,-0.04,0.01,-0.06,-0.03,-0.08,0.01,-0.01,0,0.01,-0.05,0.04,-0.08,0.08,-0.04,-0.04,0,-0.05,-0.17,0.08,0,0.05,0.06,-0.07,0.1,-0.11,-0.03,0.11,-0.05,0.11,-0.02,-0.06,-0.05,0.03,0.02,0.06,0,0,0.05,0.02,0.17,0.02,-0.11,-0.05,0.06,0.08,-0.05,-0.09,0.06,0,-0.02,0,0.03,0.01,-0.01,-0.04,-0.02,-0.09,0.03,-0.07,-0.03,-0.02,-0.01,-0.08,0.02,-0.05,-0.03,0.01,0.02,-0.01,0.05,0,-0.02,-0.03,-0.01,0.06,0,0,0,0.01,0.05,-0.02,0.02,-0.04,-0.05,-0.03,0.02,0,-0.03,0,0.03,-0.02,-0.05,0.01,-0.1,0.04,0.01,0,0.04,-0.08,-0.02,-0.06,0.26,0.03,0,0.01,-0.01,-0.01,0.03,0.08,-0.05,-0.14,0.14,-0.04,-0.04,-0.08,-0.11,0.02,-0.01,-0.05,-0.01,-0.16,0,0.15,-0.11,-0.02,0,0.02,0.08,-0.05,-0.07,0.1,-0.02,0.08,-0.09,-0.05,-0.05,0.09,-0.04,-0.05,-0.02,0.08,0.12,0,0.17,-0.06,-0.06,0,-0.03,-0.09,0.03,0.04,0.06,-0.03,-0.02,-0.12,-0.01,0.02,-0.14,0.1,0.06,0.02,0.01,-0.03,0.07,0,0,-0.09,0.01,-0.06,-0.01,0.03,-0.06,0,0.01,0.04,-0.01,-0.01,0,0.01,0.14,0.17,-0.05,-0.12,-0.03,0.03,0.01,-0.06,-0.14,0.08,-0.05,0.07,-0.05,-0.11,-0.02,-0.01,-0.01,0.1,-0.05,0.02,-0.05,-0.09,-0.06,-0.14,0.01,-0.16,0.07,-0.11,0,0.08,0.06,0.19,0.03,-0.07,-0.19,-0.09,-0.01,-0.06,-0.02,-0.61,-0.07,0.29,0.23,-0.12,0.05,-0.13,0.07,-0.08,-0.1,0.01,-0.07,-0.04,-0.12,0.06,-0.14,0.15,0.03,-0.06,0.02,0.01,0.03,-0.02,0.01,-0.05,0.02,-0.01,0,-0.08,0.14,-0.06,0.07,-0.02,-0.04,-0.02,0.05,0.04,-0.08,0.04,-0.26,0.24,0.11,0.06,-0.02,-0.04,-0.01,0.08,-0.03,-0.09,-0.06,-0.04,-0.2,-0.16,0.03,0.13,0.02,-0.02,0.07,0.08,0.04,-0.05,-0.05,0.01,0.02,-0.04,0.01,-0.05,-0.08,0.01,-0.03,0.01,0.01,-0.02,0.03,-0.05,-0.01,0.01,0.01,0.81,0.2,0.23,0.06,-0.02,0.13,-0.12,0.05,0.08,0.11,0.02,-0.12,-0.01,0.16,0.01,0.13,-0.07,0.01,-0.05,0.02,0.01,-0.05,-0.01,0.01,-0.09,0.02,0.01,0.03,-0.02,-0.1,0.03,0.02,0.08,-0.03,0.02,0.08,0.04,-0.03,0.11,0.28,-0.11,-0.02,0.1,-0.12,0.04,0.15,0.08,0.2,-0.01,-0.06,-0.03,0.13,-0.04,0.06,-0.1,-0.02,0.07,0,-0.02,-0.06,-0.02,-0.05,0.06,0.01,0.06,0.01,0.08,0,-0.01,0.07,-0.08,0.12,0.02,-0.02,0,0,-0.01,0,-0.22,0,-0.16,0.18,-0.14,0.17,-0.09,0.01,0.06,-0.08,0.01,-0.05,0,0.03,0.03,-0.05,0.07,0,-0.03,0.08,-0.07,0,0.04,-0.05,-0.04,-0.06,0.11,-0.03,0.02,0,0.03,0,0.05,-0.01,0.01,0.02,0.02,0.01,0.05,0.27,-0.1,-0.09,-0.25,0.07,-0.02,0.07,0.02,-0.03,-0.07,-0.07,-0.09,0,0.05,-0.04,-0.06,-0.02,0.03,-0.17,0.03,0.05,0.06,0.01,-0.02,0.07,-0.03,0.05,0.01,-0.07,-0.07,-0.13,0.06,0.03,0.08,-0.02,0.02,0.09,0.07,-0.14,0.72,0,-0.1,-0.06,-0.13,-0.22,-0.14,0.01,-0.18,-0.12,-0.03,-0.09,-0.23,-0.35,0.12,-0.26,0.41,0.16,-0.1,0.02,-0.01,-0.18,0.02,0.05,-0.15,-0.01,0.06,-0.19,0.08,-0.1,0,-0.11,0.13,-0.29,0.08,-0.21,-0.08,0.07,-0.01,-0.28,0.23,0.11,0.22,-0.1,-0.35,-0.09,-0.06,-0.09,-0.03,-0.08,-0.02,0.04,-0.33,-0.18,0.2,-0.14,0.07,-0.04,-0.15,-0.07,-0.07,-0.11,0.1,-0.03,0.19,0.01,0.14,-0.14,0.1,0.02,0.1,0.05,0.07,0.14,-0.01,-0.21,-0.06,0,0.41,-0.17,-0.22,0.03,-0.09,-0.25,0.33,0.09,0.13,0.17,-0.07,-0.06,-0.07,-0.14,-0.02,-0.02,0.06,0.03,-0.02,0,-0.03,0.15,0.24,-0.01,0.03,0.05,0.13,-0.18,-0.04,0.01,-0.02,0.04,-0.01,-0.06,0.02,0.05,0.03,-0.06,0.02,0.5,-0.11,-0.03,-0.28,0.08,0.1,-0.07,0.01,-0.08,0.02,0.11,0.02,0.07,0.05,-0.02,-0.05,0.07,0.08,-0.02,0.01,-0.06,-0.05,0.02,0.01,0,0,-0.01,0.17,0.06,-0.06,-0.04,-0.04,-0.07,-0.01,0.02,0.01,0,0.01,-0.03,-0.13,0.39,-0.07,-0.04,-0.01,0.04,-0.14,-0.23,-0.08,-0.16,0,-0.1,0.07,0.01,-0.07,-0.08,0.04,-0.01,0,-0.1,-0.09,0.07,-0.07,0,0.01,0.03,0.05,0,0.08,0.09,-0.1,-0.2,-0.04,-0.04,0.06,-0.1,0.03,0.05,-0.08,-0.1,0.11,0.21,-0.28,-0.25,0.32,-0.12,0,0.17,-0.01,0.15,-0.13,0.01,-0.04,0.03,-0.14,-0.11,-0.05,-0.04,-0.06,0.06,-0.15,-0.05,-0.1,0.03,0.28,-0.1,0.03,-0.06,0.01,-0.08,-0.12,0.14,-0.08,-0.03,0.13,-0.07,-0.02,-0.05,0.26,0.12,0.02,-0.02,0.1,0.08,0.04,0.16,0.03,-0.05,0,0.09,0.13,-0.03,-0.03,0.05,0.02,-0.01,-0.03,0.02,-0.01,-0.02,-0.07,0.01,0.09,-0.07,0,0.03,0.03,-0.12,-0.02,-0.13,-0.14,-0.22,0.06,0.25,0.11,0,0.05,-0.04,0.24,-0.08,0.01,-0.13,-0.11,0.12,0.01,0,-0.09,0.09,-0.11,-0.01,-0.11,-0.14,0.09,-0.02,0.12,-0.06,-0.02,-0.05,0.11,0.13,-0.01,0.1,0.01,0.11,-0.03,-0.05,0.01,0.11,0.04,-0.02,-0.1,0.22,-0.01,-0.09,0.06,-0.03,0.04,-0.06,0.05,-0.03,0.22,0.04,-0.1,-0.05,-0.03,-0.01,0.11,0.04,-0.06,0.04,0.07,0.05,0.02,-0.02,-0.04,-0.07,-0.08,-0.01,0.04,0.05,-0.08,0.07,0.01,0,-0.13,-0.05,0.11,-0.05,0.05,-0.03,0.05,0.06,0.05,0.02,0.02,0.96,-0.16,0.13,0.01,-0.07,0.15,-0.1,0,0.08,-0.03,-0.07,0.09,-0.15,0.08,-0.02,0.09,-0.02,0.03,0,0.09,0.06,0.09,-0.01,-0.02,0.04,0.05,0.22,0.03,-0.01,-0.08,0.04,-0.12,0.03,0.06,0.02,0.01,-0.05,-0.01,-0.01,0.93,-0.02,0.06,0.09,-0.3,-0.01,-0.09,0.26,0,-0.07,0.01,-0.04,-0.06,0.05,0.04,0.24,0.02,-0.02,-0.01,0.1,0.01,-0.04,0.01,0.06,-0.04,-0.07,0.15,0.01,0.05,-0.01,0.01,-0.02,0.12,-0.19,0.05,0.04,0.01,0.05,0.04,0.62,-0.02,-0.09,0.06,0.06,-0.01,0.04,-0.04,0.03,0.14,0.03,-0.01,0.04,0.02,-0.04,-0.03,0.06,0.08,-0.09,-0.11,0.09,-0.06,-0.08,0.15,-0.02,0,-0.01,0.01,-0.05,0.01,0.06,-0.01,0,0.01,0,0.01,0.02,-0.02,0,0.25,-0.3,0.04,-0.18,0.21,0.04,-0.04,0.02,0.02,-0.06,-0.1,0.03,0.04,0.18,0.04,-0.02,0.03,-0.02,-0.11,0.02,0.02,0,0.02,0.03,-0.09,0.01,0.02,-0.03,-0.08,0.08,-0.03,-0.01,0.06,0.1,0.01,-0.06,0.05,-0.18,0.06,0.01,-0.47,-0.03,-0.26,0.41,-0.14,0.07,0.11,0.16,0.14,0.01,-0.04,0.16,0,-0.01,-0.02,0.04,0.02,0.02,0.11,0.04,-0.07,0.02,-0.02,-0.11,-0.1,-0.19,0.05,-0.01,-0.05,0.09,-0.11,0.03,0.02,0.02,-0.03,-0.03,0.06,0.01,-0.69,0.07,0,-0.04,0.06,0.01,-0.22,-0.03,-0.14,0.02,0.2,0.09,-0.02,-0.08,0.01,0.01,0.03,-0.02,-0.04,-0.06,-0.05,0.01,-0.01,0.05,0.02,0.07,-0.03,-0.06,-0.02,0,0,0,-0.08,0.02,0.01,0,-0.01,0.01,0.01,0.13,-0.16,0.31,0.04,0.05,-0.12,0,-0.13,-0.06,-0.11,-0.24,-0.11,0.11,-0.1,-0.07,-0.14,0.07,-0.08,-0.05,0.07,-0.08,-0.19,-0.11,0.12,-0.11,0.05,-0.01,-0.04,0.14,0.06,-0.04,0.06,-0.14,0.15,0.12,0.02,-0.02,-0.06,-0.01,0.3,0.09,-0.14,-0.01,-0.05,-0.23,0.02,0.08,-0.01,0.1,-0.06,0.22,-0.02,0.06,0.07,0.06,0,0.08,0.11,-0.09,0,-0.08,-0.06,-0.05,0.03,-0.02,0.07,0.01,0,-0.01,0,0.01,0,0,0.02,0.1,-0.02,0.03,-0.1,0.43,0.12,-0.03,-0.05,0.07,-0.04,0.06,0.15,-0.08,-0.08,-0.02,0.05,0.08,-0.02,-0.02,0.04,0.02,-0.02,0.03,-0.04,-0.06,0.01,0,0.11,0.03,0.01,-0.01,0.02,-0.07,0.03,0,0.1,-0.01,-0.01,0.06,0.03,0.02,0.03,0.09)
IBM_Diff1_ten<-c(0.73,-0.043,0.093,0.38,-0.01,-0.31,0.151,-0.181,-0.042,-0.278,0.139,0.061,0.187,-0.667,-0.51,-0.3,0.0327,0.1273,-0.14,0.03,0.3,0.27,0.24,-0.05,-0.4496,-0.0334,0.527,-0.284,-0.11,0,0.02,-0.275,0.045,-0.32,-0.23,0.13,-0.3857,-0.2543,0.39,0.5101,-0.0501,-0.09,0.45,0.01,0.17,-0.11,-0.38,0.64,-0.39,-0.2399,0.0699,0.17,-0.2,-0.55,0.32,0.119,0.2411,0.2699,0.06,0.3075,0.1325,-0.0942,0.036,0.0082,-0.04,-0.2415,0.3957,-0.2442,-0.05,0.13,-0.103,0.033,-0.11,-0.11,-0.26,0.24,-0.13,0.5224,0.3576,0.29,-0.2825,-0.6775,-0.65,0.05,0.0296,0.0304,0.05,-0.17,-0.03,-0.23,0.1,-0.094,0.094,-0.04,-0.1,0.06,-0.21,0.06,0.05,-0.08,-0.03,-0.205,0.015,-0.24,0.21,-0.03,0.04,-0.07,0.08,0.24,0.16,0.19,0.05,-0.2801,-0.2699,-0.46,0.9,-0.02,0.31,-0.31,0.17,0.37,-0.06,0.05,-0.16,-0.07,-0.0523,0.3923,0.26,0.13,-0.01,0.2,0.26,-0.2508,0.0308,0.012,0.108,-0.32,0.0226,0.0474,-0.16,-0.07,-0.199,0.329,-0.006,-0.034,-0.113,-0.077,-0.12,0.006,-0.126,-0.3073,0.1341,-0.1768,-0.43,0.21,0.29,-0.48,-0.32,0.45,-0.321,-0.049,-0.25,-0.04,0.01,0.57,-0.02,0.3978,0.0322,-0.384,0.1897,0.0794,-0.1082,0.0931,-0.06,0.0969,0.2551,0.0165,0.0015,-0.08,-0.3511,-0.0706,-0.1583,-0.05,0.166,-0.096,0.085,0.085,-0.1,-0.222,-0.068,0.1713,-0.2713,0.08,1.18,-0.33,-0.36,0.63,0.29,0.46,0.03,-0.09,-0.3734,0.0334,0.19,-0.07,-0.24,-0.23,0.17,0.05,0.21,0.02,0.208,-0.0522,0.1442,-0.118,-0.042,0.0782,0.0581,0.0537,-0.38,-0.25,-0.42,-0.3,0.26,0.01,0.05,-0.15,0.18,0.006,0.064,-0.21,0.07,0.75,0.12,0.04,-0.26,0.23,-0.25,0.37,-0.17,0.23,0.05,0.24,0.04,0.04,0.01,0.14,-0.34,0.11,0,-0.15,0.0601,0.1199,0.0575,-0.0175,0.15,0.22,0.01,-0.02,-0.015,0.1044,-0.3564,-0.085,-0.098,0.1,-0.0903,-0.1997,0.01,-0.18,-0.19,0.43,-0.6607,0.6107,0.3,0.55,-0.27,0.07,-0.53,0.07,-0.182,-0.398,0.28,0.38,0.18,-0.04,0.23,-0.06,0,-0.24,0.19,0.05,0.02,-0.05,-0.05,0.02,0.11,-0.4034,0.0215,-0.1781,0.1904,-0.0903,-0.2201,-0.1,-0.34,-0.8428,0.3428,0.422,0.198,-0.04,0.36,-1.51,0.035,0.294,-0.189,-0.14,0.17,0.22,-0.09,0.265,-0.745,0.19,0.08,-0.05,-0.46,-0.26,0.1111,-0.0311,0.31,0.12,-0.18,0.22,0.18,-0.03,0.23,-0.081,0.056,0.315,-0.09,-0.07,-0.22,0.34,0.3611,-0.0961,-0.1756,-0.0494,-0.1324,-0.0076,-0.06,0.26,1.765,-0.009,0.314,-0.06,0.34,0.22,0.19,-0.355,-0.035,-0.2,0.06,0.03,0.1,0.095,0.115,-0.03,0.17,-0.38,-0.08,-0.02,0.0648,-0.0698,0.025,0.08,0.03,-0.36,0.0949,-0.0849,0.12,0.12,0.037,0.193,0.1129,-0.1929,0.185,-0.066,-0.249,-0.07,-0.09,0.44,-0.199,0.089,0.15,0.11,0.12,-0.1101,-0.0299,0.11,0.26,0.05,-0.14,0.16,0.0036,0.0314,0.015,0.24,0.07,0.1553,-0.0053,-0.11,0,0.05,-0.09,-0.03,-0.1,0,-0.04,-0.089,-0.081,0.006,-0.146,0.07,-0.19,0.02,0.034,-0.004,-0.05,0,0.2554,0.107,0.5516,-0.394,-0.04,0.46,-0.154,0.344,-0.36,0.02,0.0467,0.1333,0.2541,-0.1911,-0.023,-0.19,-0.023,0.003,0.1297,0.0303,0.05,-0.148,-0.041,0.009,0.09,0.01,-0.05,0.19,0.01,-0.4182,-0.1918,0.15,-0.09,0.0667,0.1033,0.01,-0.05,-0.25,0.09,1.125,-0.727,0.322,0.234,-0.014,-0.31,-0.05,-0.22,-0.07,-0.19,-0.25,0.31,-0.05,0.23,0.41,-0.23,0.22,0.19,-0.24,-0.12,0,-0.11,-0.11,-0.16,-0.19,0.21,-0.03,-0.11,0,-0.14,-0.1,-0.09,0.18,0.02,0.06,-0.03,-0.312,0.062,0.32,0.179,0.4458,-0.2848,-0.24,-0.56,-0.25,-0.076,-0.414,-0.268,0.173,-0.165,0.355,0.0254,-0.0304,-0.03,-0.09,0.15,0.02,-0.15,-0.329,0.1097,-0.0807,-0.12,0.303,-0.2122,0.0902,0.039,-0.2991,-0.0309,0.02,0.142,-0.032,-0.04,0.22,0.06,-0.04,0.1281,-0.0081,0,0.65,-0.329,0.304,0.215,0.58,0.11,0.14,-0.16,0.46,-0.3641,-0.0559,-0.22,0.06,-0.53,-0.04,-0.45,-0.18,0.04,-0.07,0.15,-0.232,-0.138,0.23,-0.21,0.21,0.28,-0.025,-0.205,-0.04,0.1,-0.13,0.15,-0.1,-0.16,0.18,0.15,0.06,-0.17,0.11,-0.308,-0.142,0.16,0.18,0.26,0.03,-0.13,-0.085,0.475,-0.07,-0.07,0.09,-0.05,-0.1,-0.29,0.05,-0.11,-0.215,-0.15,-0.1,0.095,-0.1,-0.09,0.05,0.04,0.1,-0.03,-0.0799,0.0799,0,-0.02,0,-0.0399,0.0299,-0.23,0.09,0.04,0.04,0.06,0.69,0,-0.48,-0.06,-0.21,0.118,-0.158,-0.58,-0.08,-0.04,0.3,-0.44,0.2,-0.17,-0.0807,-0.0543,-0.225,-0.24,-0.1,0.155,-0.335,-0.135,0.255,0.14,-0.2,0.28,-0.4,-0.45,0.17,-0.069,0.1991,-0.1601,0.26,-0.345,-0.255,0.25,0.1,-0.04,-0.13,0.05,0.08,-0.48,0.38,0.01,-0.5,0.26,-0.23,-0.33,-0.09,-0.26,0.1899,0.2001,0.59,0.12,-0.1648,0.1348,-0.29,0.05,0.1,-0.08,-0.14,-0.25,-0.11,0.01,-0.3,0.252,-0.212,-0.08,-0.02,0.07,-0.17,-0.16,0.26,-0.16,0.17,-0.2,-0.26,-0.1,2.164,0.636,-0.11,0.372,0.0123,-0.1813,0.107,-0.152,0.162,0.07,0.14,-0.306,-0.114,0.34,0.27,0.03,0.5818,-0.2018,-0.16,-0.2,0,0.12,-0.2166,0.0256,0.261,0.16,-0.19,-0.02,-0.11,0.42,-0.38,0.3021,0.0979,0.0331,-0.0041,0.021,-0.15,-0.41,0.15,0.34,0.17,0.3499,0.0901,0.61,0.42,-0.55,0.11,-0.39,0.27,0.23,0.08,0.1137,-0.1637,-0.083,0.173,-0.282,0.0112,-0.031,0.0018,-0.0881,0.0941,-0.161,0.225,-0.04,0.332,-0.201,-0.021,-0.126,0.134,-0.018,0.116,-0.076,-0.22,-0.04,-0.14,-0.077,-0.273,0.11,-0.45,-0.21,-0.3344,-0.2056,0.1,0.21,-0.16,0.23,-0.19,0.26,-0.16,-0.09,-0.27,0.15,0.13,0.25,-0.23,-0.02,0.13,0.3199,0.0101,-0.1,0.13,-0.01,-0.04,-0.26,0.07,-0.73,-0.04,-0.07,0.09,-0.1101,0.1701,-1.22,0.22,0.08,0.35,0.187,-0.287,-0.11,-0.09,0.16,0.91,0.35,0.04,0.19,0.38,-0.27,0.15,-0.27,0.25,0.18,0.224,-0.054,-0.01,0.6,0.27,0.17,0.06,0.05,0.172,-0.042,-0.21,0.02,0.1,-0.02,-0.11,0.239,0.171,-0.25,0.125,0.104,-0.228,0.109,-0.2654,0.0054,0.0084,0.0816,0.15,-0.5276,0.2476,-0.31,-0.09,-0.07,-0.14,0.03,0.1501,-0.3201,-0.09,0.02,-0.02,0.1,-0.32,0.3,-0.11,-0.05,0.04,0.43,0.05,0.27,-0.3199,-0.4001,0.08,-0.23,0.02,0.38,-0.19,-0.37,0.14,0.11,0.05,0.0581,-0.0085,0.2504,-0.43,-0.04,-0.07,2.23,-0.07,-0.32,-0.34,0.21,-0.28,-0.04,0.03,0.22,0.05,-0.14,-0.22,-0.01,-0.14,-0.16,-0.04,0.18,-0.15,-0.06,0.035,0.296,0.149,0.1599,0.0901,-0.07,-0.004,0.414,0.0701,-0.1394,0.2993,-0.26,0.38,-0.28,0.02,-0.31,0.445,-0.13,-0.195,-0.34,1.87,0.7803,0.2301,0.5096,0.181,-0.419,-0.201,-0.3099,0.5339,0.225,0.67,0.18,0.42,-0.35,-0.0836,0.366,-0.4404,-0.282,0.58,0.17,0.643,0.2303,0.1897,0.807,-0.1,0.382,-0.232,0.1,-0.157,-0.293,0.11,-0.23,0.1,0.5,0.17,0.0339,0.0161,-0.002,-0.108,-0.07,0.113,-0.103,0.02,-0.54,-0.36,-0.1,-0.33,-0.22,-0.01,0.27,0.4,-0.39,-0.3099,-0.1151,-0.275,-0.33,0.07,0.42,0.12,0.11,-0.23,0.02,-0.59,-0.21,-0.25,0.46,0.0194,-0.2994,0.399,0.071,0.16,0.38,-0.25,0.13,-0.135,0.155,-0.1308,-0.4892,-1.58,0.03,-0.2,0.35,-0.4603,0.1503,-0.26,-0.146,0.1754,-0.4284,0.2983,0.1307,-0.121,-0.069,0.18,-0.281,0.261,0.5,-0.7872,-0.2328,-0.04,-0.049,-0.011,0.11,-0.5116,-0.0884,0.1782,-0.0482,-0.15,0.298,-0.294,0.0743,0.0317,0.0089,0.1911,0.4,0.235,-0.535,-0.1,1.451,0.549,-0.34,0.14,-0.01,0.08,0.1801,-0.0301,0.18,0.1701,0.0599,-0.28,-0.177,-0.633,-0.1031,0.4131,-0.1204,-0.1096,-0.09,0.06,-0.31,-0.214,-0.086,0.069,-0.099,0.08,-0.16,-0.6156,-0.2144,0.56,-0.07,-0.16,0.196,0.004,0.08,0.122,-0.212,-0.04,0.3,2.16,-0.17,0.45,-0.01,-0.23,0.04,0.04,-0.43,-0.06,-0.2301,-0.0499,0.18,0.04,0.1,0.25,0.39,0.13,0.04,0.02,0.34,0.24,-0.182,-0.178,0.114,0.086,-0.031,-0.209,0.26,-0.103,-0.227,-0.05,-0.08,0.113,-0.07,-0.093,0.0962,-0.2862,-0.16,-0.2,0.59,0.77,0.23,0.6465,0.0635,-0.66,0.37,0.07,-0.46,-0.32,-0.04,-0.06,0.095,-0.105,-0.045,-0.026,0.321,0.28,0.09,0.18,0.17,-0.08,0.06,0.16,0.34,-0.304,-0.096,0.0021,-0.1221,0.146,0.024,-0.006,-0.128,0.024,-0.017,-0.023,-0.11,0.13,-0.15,-0.8801,-0.1299,-0.24,-0.12,-0.33,0.59,-0.07,0.09,0.118,0.002,-0.17,0.12,0.17,-0.05,0,-0.23,-0.28,0.02,-0.11,0.09,-0.0883,0.2233,-0.225,-0.2,0.03,-0.28,0.2,0.3,0.015,0.065,0.12,-0.06,-0.009,-0.049,0.078,0.075,0.295,-0.05,0.02,-1.1,0.14,0.18,-0.01,0.1652,0.0865,-0.1717,0.1264,0.0536,-0.1,0.1,-0.08,0.07,-0.029,-0.041,0.011,0.009,0.04,-0.16,0.0549,0.0581,-0.013,0.09,-0.04,0.0414,-0.0214,-0.01,0.05,0.01,-0.04,-0.119,-0.0102,0.0792,-0.152,0.052,0.01,0.01,-0.27,0.07,0.32,-0.05,0.2,0.183,0.3909,-0.2639,-0.05,0.246,-0.156,-0.5,0.08,0.51,-0.14,-0.4,-0.08,-0.39,-0.07,-0.01,-0.12,0.25,-0.02,0.75,0.22,-0.17,0.11,-0.105,-0.145,0,0.28,-0.5039,-0.8061,-0.52,0.18,-0.38,0.41,0.0534,-0.2034,-0.02,0,0.85,-0.16,0.33,0.132,-0.342,-0.18,-0.1498,0.5098,0.18,0.44,0.73,-0.11,-0.0985,-0.1515,-0.25,0.24,-0.12,0.481,-0.101,-0.0645,0.3655,-0.121,0.3007,0.3893,-0.2693,0.2193,-0.289,-0.038,0.0079,-0.0309,0.186,0.224,-0.07,0.441,0.0088,-0.0068,-0.5845,-0.2185,0.07,-1.36,-0.085,-0.075,0.751,-0.011,-0.378,0.398,-0.25,-0.01,0.25,0.06,-0.24,-0.1632,-0.5168,0.11,0.1303,0.1997,-0.045,-0.025,-0.16,-0.063,0.093,0.29,-0.02,-0.01,-0.13,0.1,-0.1,-0.11,0.12,0.03,0.17,0.01,-0.0367,0.0867,-0.05,0.26,-0.3,-0.15,1.64,-0.61,0.08,-0.21,0.37,0.06,-0.27,-0.01,0.09,0.22,0.2851,0.0849,0.09,-0.15,0.15,-0.11,-0.14,0.14,0.0152,-0.1052,-0.2,0.07,0.18,-0.04,0.01,0.14,-0.07,0.4,0.27,0.28,0.13,0.34,0.02,0.03,0.15,-0.02,0.31,-0.01,-0.26,1.0592,0.7223,0.3585,0.15,-0.105,-0.245,-0.38,0.0401,0.6899,-0.195,0.315,-0.15,-0.15,0.16,-0.16,-0.5,0.2999,-0.1299,0.212,-0.0862,-0.2258,0.35,-0.59,-0.13,-0.27,0.06,-0.21,-0.64,-0.58,0.24,0.17,-0.24,0.27,-0.64,0.2199,-0.1099,0.44,0.22,-1.19,-0.16,0.06,0.16,-0.545,-0.13,1.1497,0.09,-0.3347,0.45,-0.1953,0.5453,-0.3,-0.315,-0.145,-0.195,0.375,-0.1052,-0.1448,0.09,0.105,-0.095,-0.35,0,0.01,0.08,0.04,-0.1551,0.0951,-0.64,0.2649,0.0201,-0.055,0.195,0.095,0.4648,-0.2298,-0.31,-0.025,-0.32,1.28,0.065,0.325,0.42,0.64,-0.17,0.21,0.01,0.19,-0.261,-0.379,-0.19,0.62,0.17,-0.541,-0.299,0.35,0.08,0.02,0.19,0.0158,-0.0103,-0.4002,-0.0153,0.101,-0.0868,-0.0203,0.2684,-0.2123,-0.2962,0.1162,0.06,0.002,-0.266,-0.016,0.28,0.136,-0.026,0.18,-0.5,-0.53,0.28,-0.68,-0.29,0.42,0.07,0.29,-0.572,-0.098,0.19,0.28,0.52,-0.73,-0.17,-0.14,0.16,0.14,-0.27,-0.3301,-0.1199,0.26,-0.03,0.065,0.135,0.16,0.53,-0.24,0.23,-0.01,0.31,0.01,0.04,-0.11,0.372,0.018,-0.49,-0.07,0.15,0.64,-0.16,1.14,-0.28,-0.46,0.36,0.06,-0.98,-0.47,0.05,0.46,-0.09,-0.09,-0.41,0.06,-0.01,0.385,-0.135,0.14,0.04,-0.05,-0.07,0.13,0,-0.32,0.095,-0.015,-0.09,-0.12,-0.04,0.21,-0.1,0.15,-0.245,-0.125,-0.03,0.06,0.1757,-0.5457,-7.87,0.4675,0.0025,0.5,-0.29,-0.17,0.5,0.25,0.17,-0.38,-0.0601,0.4101,-0.26,-0.36,0.07,0.44,-0.2599,0.2887,0.1612,-0.109,-0.07,0.319,0.15,0.2371,0.1629,-0.263,-0.037,-0.32,0.0666,0.0424,-0.147,-0.192,0.193,0.238,-0.181,0.0565,0.1235,-0.2,-0.01,0.86,0.97,0.4,-0.0894,-0.1606,-0.12,0.07,0.22,-0.053,0.195,0.18,-0.122,-0.288,-0.11,-0.112,0.15,-0.08,0.08,0.15,0.2633,-0.0093,-0.405,0.191,0.25,0.03,-0.04,0.06,0.08,0.2,-0.19,0.12,-0.07,-0.008,-0.232,-0.18,-0.0315,0.0515,-0.14,0.18,-0.05,-0.405,-0.125,-0.11,0.17,-0.29,0.05,0.23,0.2991,0.0149,0.017,0.017,0.202,-0.1332,-0.0228,0.1516,0.1444,0.0524,-0.107,-0.0654,-0.2,0.05,0,0.1,0.03,0.07,0.02,0.04,0.05,-0.01,-0.2607,0.2623,0.0284,-0.1946,0.0796,0.0593,-0.1143,-0.12,-0.05,-1.23,-0.42,0.1,-0.146,-0.304,0.79,0.14,-0.056,-0.264,0.16,-0.2199,-0.2401,0.18,0.07,0.01,-0.26,0.13,0.159,0.131,0.321,0.149,-0.08,0.42,-0.01,0.18,-0.3,0.06,0.1299,-0.2199,0.15,0.01,0.01,-0.09,0.035,0.05,0.255,0.43,-0.339,-0.311,0.11,-1.34,0.51,0.16,0.05,0.05,-0.17,-0.32,-0.03,0.09,-0.15,0.1,0.16,0.11,0.23,-0.23,-0.05,-0.03,-0.06,-0.09,0.14,-0.01,0.05,-0.07,-0.34,-0.05,-0.15,-0.1,0,-0.08,0.13,-0.04,0.23,0.12,0.04,-0.03,-0.28,-0.06,-0.13,-0.27,-0.69,0.07,0.24,0,0.1201,0.0549,-0.095,-0.13,0.13,-0.12,-0.02,0.05,-0.03,0.23,-0.25,0.12,-0.1,-0.1,-0.185,-0.035,-0.015,0.015,0.1,-0.03,0.16,0.05,0,-0.22,0.08,0.1796,-0.1396,0.08,0.004,-0.004,0.43,0.13,-0.145,-0.245,2.27,1.03,0.061,-0.261,0.53,-0.22,0.34,0.21,-0.0026,0.3526,-0.69,-0.47,0.275,0.255,-0.27,0.115,0.384,0.181,-0.06,0,-0.328,-0.477,-0.285,-0.27,0.12,-0.18,0.05,0.16,0.33,0.19,0.129,0.211,-0.35,0.24,0.31,0.025,-0.135,-0.0901,-0.1699,2.11,-0.23,-0.22,-0.95,0.56,-0.2,0.58,0.19,0.04,0.06,-0.21,0.39,-0.0699,0.0398,-0.0199,0.39,-0.09,0.15,0.04,-0.13,0.17,-0.08,-0.18,0.16,-0.04,-0.0199,0.1599,-0.26,0.13,-0.12,-0.01,0.12,0.06,-0.03,-0.12,0.12,-0.25,-0.16,-0.09,0.38,-0.1099,0.1699,0.16,-0.21,0.15,0.121,0.319,0.19,0,-0.3747,-0.2153,0.06,0.19,0.23,0.44,-0.0399,-0.0001,0.1,-0.05,0.09,-0.01,-0.16,-0.09,0.02,-0.05,0.21,0.05,-0.1,0.05,-0.12,0.25,-0.14,-0.17,-0.08,0.08,0.1,-0.36,0.24)
```

For this data-set I would like to run the cross correlation analysis which is done through usage of ccf():

```
m=500
k=50

ccf(panel.first =c(abline(v=seq(-m, m, by=k), col="gray"),abline(v=0, col="red")),
MU_Diff1_ten,IBM_Diff1_ten,lag.max =m,ylab="MU-IBM(10 Min.)",main="",xaxt="n",xlab="")
```

The plot looks like this:
[image]

Now, I would like to paint, in green, every lag which crosses the border interval of +- 0.07. How to do that ?? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your giant long sample data lines are too big to paste... Make something simpler?

Comment: @Spacedman: triple-click on the code box will select the entire line :)

Comment: Yeah, but when I paste into R in a console it gets truncated. Needed to paste to a file and source it. Prob a Linux/X problem but giant lines like that can be problematic and unnecessary if you generate random data for examples.

Comment: @Spacedman: that is odd, I don't seem to have that issue under Fedora 20. Anyway agree that a call to `rnorm` would have been probably enough :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is not using the `ccf` function to plot the CCF, but rather save its output in a variable and use `plot` on it.

So, for instance

```
# Note plot=0 to prevent graphical output
my.ccf <- ccf(MU_Diff1_ten, IBM_Diff1_ten, lag.max=m, plot=0)

ccf.color <- ifelse(my.ccf$acf>0.07 | my.ccf$acf < -0.07 , 
                    "green", "black")

plot(my.ccf$lag, my.ccf$acf, t="h", col=ccf.color, lwd=1.5,
     las=1, xlab="", ylab="CCF")

abline(v=seq(-m, m, by=k), col="gray")
abline(v=0, col="red")
```

Comment: `plot=FALSE` makes it a bit more obvious!

Comment: This is so elegant way!! Thank you very much. Instead abline() I will apply the plot(panel.first =c(abline(v=seq(-m, m, by=k), col="gray"), abline(v=0, col="red")),my.ccf$lag, my.ccf$acf, t="h", col=ccf.color, lwd=1.5, las=1, xlab="", ylab="CCF") , because grid lines should be behind the plot in order to make visible every lag value (lag 0 is not visible for example).

Comment: @user44037: you may also want to have a look at `getAnywhere(plot.acf)` to see the actual code used by `ccf` to do the plot (note that `ccf` outputs an `acf` object, so it's `plot.acf` and not `plot.ccf`).